# How to associate a label with the radio button?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using `Html.RadioButtonFor` and want to know what is the best practise to use it. For example, following are two approaches where Option-1 gives me desired result. I am just declaring `DeliveryFeeType` in my model and using `Label` overthere.

Option - 1:

.ASPX

```
<div id="delivery-fee-config" >
    <div>
        <%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.DeliveryFeeType) %>
    </div>
    <div>
        <%= Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.DeliveryFeeType, "All") %>
        <%= Html.Label("All") %>
    </div>
    <div>
        <%= Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.DeliveryFeeType, "Flat Fee") %>
        <%= Html.Label("Flat Fee") %>
    </div>
     <div>
        <%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.FlatFeeAmount) %>
        <%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FlatFeeAmount, new {maxlength="5"}) %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Model:

```
[DisplayName("Select Delivery Fee Type")]
public string DeliveryFeeType { get; set; }
```

Output:
[image]

Now, here I want to use `LabelFor` where properties are declared in `model`. What I do not like is, `All` and `FlatFee` always comes as false when I debug. It looks like I am just using them to display labels on UI. Can I make them `true` or `false` based on `radio button` selection? If yes, how can I do that?

Option - 2:

.ASPX

```
<div id="delivery-fee-config" >
    <div>
        <%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.DeliveryFeeType) %>
    </div>
    <div>
        <%= Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.DeliveryFeeType, "All") %>
        <%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.All) %>
    </div>
    <div>
        <%= Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.DeliveryFeeType, "Flat Fee") %>
        <%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.FlatFee) %>
    </div>
    <div>
        <%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.FlatFeeAmount) %>
        <%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FlatFeeAmount, new {maxlength="5"}) %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Model:

```
[DisplayName("Select Delivery Fee Type")]
public string DeliveryFeeType { get; set; }

[DisplayName("All")]
public bool All { get; set; }

[DisplayName("Flat Fee")]
public bool FlatFee { get; set; }
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Your not generating any form controls for `All` or `FlatFee` so no value is posted, and therefore they are their default value (`false`). But why do you think you need those properties?

Comment: @StephenMuecke In the same page I saw couple of properties which follows that pattern. Like this,

`<div>
 <%=Html.LabelFor(m => m.EnableDelivery) %>
 <%=Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.EnableDelivery) %>
</div>

[DisplayName("Enable delivery for this store")]
public bool EnableDelivery { get; set; }`
So I was wondering, can I do similar thing with `RadioButton` as well.

Comment: Is your question about how to associate a label with the radio button?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I think yes. I can change the title if it is misleading.

Comment: OK, I'll add an answer, but I'll edit the question as well to explain what you want (or you can do it) - its not really clear what you trying to do.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sorry about the confusion. I want to understand that how can I bind label with radio button. If it is still unclear, please edit the question per your thoughts and I'll see if that helps me or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To associate `<label>` element you can either wrap the form control in a `<label>` or you can use the `for` attribute to associate it with the `id` attribute of the control.

The problem with the `RadioButtonFor()` method is that it generates duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid html, so you should either remove it (if wrapped in a `<label>`) or explicitly set it.

Option 1

```
<label>
    <%= Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.DeliveryFeeType, "All", new { id = "" }) %>
    <span>All</span>
</label>
<label>
    <%= Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.DeliveryFeeType, "Flat Fee", new { id = "" }) %>
    <span>Flat Fee</span>
</label>
```

Option 2

```
<%= Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.DeliveryFeeType, "All", new { id = "all" }) %>
<%= Html.Label("All", new { @for = "all" }) %>
<%= Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.DeliveryFeeType, "All", new { id = "flatfee" }) %>
<%= Html.Label("Flat Fee", new { @for = "flatfee" }) %>
```

Comment: I am not getting the results by using these options. Option 2 throws an error `} expected`. Looks good to me but errors out. Still `All` and `FlatFee` comes as false even though if I check any of the radio button.

Comment: Error on which line? And what do you mean _not getting the results_? And you need to delete the 2 `bool` properties from your model - your binding to property `DeliveryFeeType` (not `bool All` and `bool FlatFee` - those are not required and make no sense to include in the model)

Comment: Error in option-2 near for in `Html.Label`. If I took those two properties out then I can get the answer with option-1 from  my question.

Comment: Oops, needs to be `@for` (at least in razor - but can remember if that also works with the `aspx` engine)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do something like this:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>@Html.DisplayNameFor( m => m.Foo )</legend>

    <label>@Html.RadioButtonFor( m => m.Foo, "Value1" ) Value One</label>
    <label>@Html.RadioButtonFor( m => m.Foo, "Value2" ) Value Two</label>
    <label>@Html.RadioButtonFor( m => m.Foo, "Value3" ) Value Three</label>
</fieldset>
```

Or this:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>@Html.DisplayNameFor( m => m.Foo )</legend>

    <label for="radio1">Value One</label>
    @html.RadioButtonFor( m => m.Foo, "Value1", new { id="radio1" } )

    <label for="radio2">Value Two</label>
    @html.RadioButtonFor( m => m.Foo, "Value2", new { id="radio2" } )

    <label for="radio3">Value Three</label>
    @html.RadioButtonFor( m => m.Foo, "Value3", new { id="radio3" } )

</fieldset>
```

This is because a single ViewModel property corresponds to the holder of the value, not the individual property values itself - remember that in HTML radio buttons present *multiple* `<input />` elements for the same form key/value pair (whereas checkboxes present one input for each key/value pair).

Another issue is that MVC's generation of `id=""` property values is incorrect:it will generate duplicates because it's based entirely off the property name, so you need to override the `id=""` property manually (so in actuality the first example I gave will give you invalid HTML markup due to duplicate `id=""` property values).